# Matlab datastore timetable dates from filename

Tags: matlab, datastore, timetable

I have a lot of CSV files for different days with time values and data inside.

```
Filename = Date (Year,Month,Day)
Inside File:
    time 1- Data
    time 2- Data
    etc.
```

When I read the files as Datastore I want the filename dates with the times as timetable. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: [`dlmread()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) or [`readmatrix()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readmatrix.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use readmatrix() function. It has a lot of parameters to read a file and format it into a variable.
Check the link below:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readmatrix.html